# Javascript RegExp in htaccess

Tags: javascript, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following RegEx in Javascript:

```
    var re1 = '(~)';
    var re2 = '([a-z])';
    var re3 = '([a-z])';
    var re4 = '(\\d)';
    var re5 = '([a-z])';
    var re6 = '(\\d)';
    var matchExp  = new RegExp(re1 + re2 + re3 + re4 + re5 + re6, ["i"]);
    var match = window.location.href.match(matchExp);
    var shortcode = match == null ? "" : match[1];
```

What I am trying here is shortcodes, I want any url such as /~Xx0X0 to be redirected to /create.html.
Where X/x is a non-whitespace character and 0 is a digit.

**How would I use the Regex in .htaccess mod_rewrite?**
I hope that I explained it all correctly.

**Shortcode Format**

- ~

  Uppercase Character

  Lowercase Character

  Digit

  Uppercase Character

  Digit

Answer (score 1):

You can put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^~[A-Z][a-z][0-9][A-Z][0-9]$ /create.html [L,R=301]
```

#### Reference: [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)

Comment: thank you! would it be possible to limit the shortcode to 6 characters (including ~)?

Comment: As @tenub: commented it is already limited 6 character including `~`